# clang-format: single-line blocks on next line

Tags: c++, clang-format

Is there a way to get clang-format to produce the following formatting:

```cpp
void foo()
{
    if(cond)
    { return; }
}

void f(int x)
{ return 2*x; }
```

I.e. I want always to see break before `{`, so I have

```
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel:  true
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: Always
  AfterEnum:       true
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct:     true
  AfterUnion:      true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true
  BeforeLambdaBody: false
  BeforeWhile:     false
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
  SplitEmptyNamespace: false
```

however, I want short statements to be on a single line, i.e.

```cpp
{ return; }
// vs
{
    return;
}
```

So far, I am noticing that even with

```
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
```

those blocks are expanded into 3 lines.
If I set

```
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: AllIfsAndElse
```

I still get the same thing
I would like a configuration something like "AllowShortBlocksWhateverTheyAre"